# Using UI tests in Continuous Testing

Tags: java, ui-testing, continuous-testing

I am planning to write some UI tests for a legacy Java EE application. Can anyone with similar experience recommend a tool for this? (I am thinking of going ahead with Selenium). Also do you recommend putting these tests as a part of the CD pipeline (my concern is because they are usually a little fragile)? (It will be great if you guys could share some strategies e.g. part with CD part as a separate daily regression)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a good pointer.   Re-think your approach!
http://googletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/just-say-no-to-more-end-to-end-tests.html

Also read about the Test Pyramid.
http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html

Some people will disagree... depends on the calibre of teams you're working with, and the levels of stress they're under to deliver!